# Is possible to do a Top Ten and a JOIN in the same job with Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have two files: Posts and Users. I need to get the top 10 users by posts, something that in SQL should be:

```
    SELECT us.name, COUNT(po.id) AS NumberOfPost FROM User us INNER JOIN Post po on
 po.userId = us.id GROUP BY us.name ORDER BY NumberOfPost DESC;
```

There is possible to do this with only one Job? without the need of a Job to make the JOIN and a Job to do the Top Ten? i must follow the mapreduce pattern of "Top Ten" but i don't have to follow any join Pattern in this case. There is a way to do it with one Job only?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, the SQL you wrote works as is in Hive. Just need to add a LIMIT 10 and you're done.

Comment: my question is: how to do it with mapreduce with only one Job, using the top ten design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to implement this in Hive. Execute the below mentioned query to do the top 10

```
 SELECT us.name, COUNT(po.id) AS NumberOfPost FROM User us INNER JOIN Post po on po.userId = us.id GROUP BY us.name ORDER BY NumberOfPost DESC Limit 10;
```